# How to make and display all rgb colors in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a flutter page like this:

please check URL : https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/color-wheel-palette-rgb-ryb-cymk-1665876799

So when I click on it a rgb colors circle open like it opens in photoshop or other photo editing apps. And I am able to change the color and that color will be than appear as background of screen

If you know the solution then write Inform Me:
Thanks.

Comment: Inform Me: Thanks.

Comment: Colors.fromRGBO(r,g,b,opacity);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_circle_color_picker) This may help. This is the Color picker.

Comment: Thanks rikit kumar.

Comment: hope this fulfills your requirements.